# How does Picasa relate to Google Plus Photos?

Tags: google-plus-photos, picasa-web-albums

How do Google Plus Photos, and Picasa relate to each other? Are they different names for the same thing? Or different interfaces to the same photo albums?

http://picasaweb.google.com/ looks quite different than `https://plus.google.com/${my account id}/photos`, but they show the same photo albums, thus the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the services/products provided by Google, both are completely different, it is just that they are linked with your common Google ID which you can use for any Google services: Google Docs, Translate, Blogger, Orkut, etc. To see more [**Click Here**](http://www.google.com/about/products/). So the photos you upload to Google Plus actually gets saved in Picasa. In short your account is linked with different Google services.

Comment: So is it fair to say these are two separate apps, that interact with the same image store?

Comment: Yes, they are completely two separate Google services, Google Plus is social networking, and Picasa is an image uploading service, they are just inter linked. You can use any Google service like YouTube, Orkut etc with your single Google ID.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand that you can use many apps with a single sign-on... it was the images from one service showing up in the other that was throwing me off.

Comment: Ya, you got it right & you welcome :)

Comment: Rumor is that Picasa is to be shortly renamed to Google Photos. Whether it's also merged to the Photo app used by Google+ remains to be seen.